# Send shortcut to Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, console, shortcut, eclipse-cdt

i got a project to complete with Eclipse's CDT. My Project is intend to listen for various shortcuts while it is running (normally from a terminal or command promt). While running under Eclipse, these shortcuts the programm is listening to(e.g. CTRL+C, ...) won't work, because Eclipse is receives shortcuts on its own.

So, my Question is, is it possible to send a shortcut to my application while it is running in an Eclipse console?

Greetings, Ben

Comment: I don't think this is possible looking at the code for `ProcessConsole`.

Comment: I'm afraid, you're right. Seems that there's no possibility to do so what i expect.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) plugin for eclipse. That plugin has a Terminal view. You can use that view to run the project and you will be able to send keyboard shortcuts to it from within eclipse.